# Push Notification with an authentication enabled client URL

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Question : How can we subscribe for push notification with a basic authentication enabled URL?

We are developing a client exchange application in which one of the feature would require a timely notification from the exchange server. For this we decided to subscribe for push notification by providing a client web service URL. This client URL is enabled with basic authentication. Our question is how to provide this authentication details when we request for a push notification subscription? Can we somehow provide this credential in clientdata tag  ?

Thanks and Regards,

Anish

Answer (score 0):

No Push notifications in EWS are Anonymous by design the SubscriptionId is one thing you could use as a validation on the client end as it unique to the current subscription your listening for and will be available inside the SOAP message. Otherwise if you proxy the push through an intermediary would be another way of doing it.

Have you had a look at the actually data that is returned in a Push, the only thing you get is the EWSId's of the Item (or folders) and details of what type of notification is it is (along with the subscription id). No Message information is disclosed within a push and it always requires that you connect back the Exchange Server to get any details about items involved.

If you really can't live with an non authenticated endpoint then I would suggest you take a look at Streaming notifications https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458792%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx . These rely on the client maintaining an Authenticated connection to the server at all times.